# create global non-cached variable

Tags: symfony1, global-variables

How can i create a global variable in Symfony, but one that will never be cached?

I basically want to be able to get `BaseForm` token key anywhere in my app without the need to create a new instance of it every time..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a static method and store the token you need in a static variable.

```
// /lib/form/BaseForm.class.php
protected static $token = null;

public static getToken(){
  if(is_null(self::$token)){
    $form = new BaseForm();
    self::$token = $form->getCSRFToken();
  }
  return self::$token;
}

public static setToken($){
  self::$token = 
}
```

You use it then

```
BaseForm::getToken();
```